# VS2010, ASP.NET - количество строк в gridView

Tags: asp.net, c#, entity-framework

**Добрый день!**

Имеются на форме 2 элемента gridView. Нужно подсчитать количество строк в каждом из них. Paging не применяется. Linq, к сожалению, тоже. Есть возможность использовать EntityFramework, но я его пока только изучаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно подсчитать строки в gridView?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = gridView1.Rows.Count
```